# Install Windows without start menu

Tags: windows, boot, start-menu, deployment

I have an WPF application that is intended to run without a physical keyboard (touch).

The application runs on full screen but in case it crashes, the user can access via the start menu the file explorer.

Is there a way to install Windows without start menu? It needs to be Windows 7 or higher.

Comment: Did that once, it's called Kiosk mode

Comment: You are looking for third-party Kiosk solution.  Windows 8 and higher support Kiosk mode.  Windows 7 requires a third-party solution.  Windows 8 and higher will only Windows Store applications in Kiosk mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill explorer:

> Windows Key + R > type 'cmd' > type 'taskkill /IM explorer.exe /f'

The start button and taskbar will dissappear.

Comment: I withdraw my earlier compliant about this answer.  As per our policy on leaving a signature in your content, I went ahead and removed it, see the [help center](http://superuser.com/help/behavior) for details.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to **install** windows without a start menu.
That doesn't mean you can't [temporarily] remove the start menu and taskbar, however.

FIRST WAY:
<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `taskkill /IM explorer.exe /f`.
However, I don't recommend this because it will force you to open task manager in order to use the file explorer: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> (Then hit task manager, click `New task` and `explorer.exe` ).

SECOND WAY:
While this may be less appealing, it is less dangerous and more useful.

<kbd>R CLICK</kbd> Taskbar & click properties
Check Auto-hide taskbar and small icons.

This should give you enough screen real estate to continue working as if it were fulscreen.

Also, if you are working in Windows 8/10 apps, use tablet mode. This will fulscreen the app.